# JavaScript - Show chart only when requested

Tags: javascript

I'm completely new to JavaScript and want to show a chart when I click a button. More precisely, I have a  field, where you can write something, and I want to show the chart with the name "Example" when I type "Example" in the field.
Right now, I have a chart, which is always shown, and a field where I can type in "Name" and it shows me "Hello Name" if I click the button. It looks like this:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <title>Project</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js"> </script> 

 </head>

<body>
    <div id="barchart" style="width:1200px;height:400px"></div>
    var Hashtag, data1, options1, chart1;
    Hashtag = [[gt(2016,09,06),1],[gt(2016,07,30),1],[gt(2016,03,06),1],[gt(2016,09,27),1],[gt(2016,06,06),1]];
    data1 =[ {data: Hashtag, color: "blue", label: "Amount Hashtags"}];
    options1={
        series: {bars: {show: true}},
        xaxis: {mode: "time",tickSize: [10, "day"]},
        legend: {noColumns: 0, position: "nw"}        
        };
  $(document).ready(function(){
  chart1 = $.plot($('#barchart'),data1, options1);
    });
  function gt(year,month,day) {
        return new Date(year,month-1,day).getTime();
</script>
     <label for="eingabe">
   Ihr Name:
   <input id="feld" name="eingabe" />
 </label>
 <button id="knopf" type="button" onclick="NameEinfg()">
    Klick mich!
 </button>
 <div id="bereich"></div>

 <script>
    function NameEinfg(){
       if (document.getElementById('feld').value==''){
          document.getElementById('bereich').innerHTML ="Hallo Unbekannter";}
       else {
          document.getElementById('bereich').innerHTML ="Hallo "+document.getElementById("feld").value;}
       }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the edited code:
    `
     
       
       Project

#### Amount of Hashtags used from January 2016 to September 2016

```
<div id="barchart" style="display: none"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript">



 var Hashtag, data1, options1, chart1;

  Hashtag = [[gt(2016,09,06),1],[gt(2016,07,30),1],[gt(2016,03,06),1],[gt(2016,09,27),1],[gt(2016,06,06),2]];



  // *BC*   Daten werden zusammengefasst in einer Variable, damit plot sie aufrufen kann
  data1 =[ {data: Hashtag, color: "blue", label: "Amount Hashtags"}];


  // *BC*   Angabe von Veränderungen am Graphen
  options1={
    series: {bars: {show: true}},
    xaxis: {mode: "time",tickSize: [10, "day"]},
    legend: {noColumns: 0, position: "nw"}        
    };



// *BC*   Plottet Barchart mit zuvor definierten Daten und Optionen
  $(document).ready(function(){
chart1 = $.plot($('#barchart'),data1, options1);
});

// Gibt Zeit in js-Format aus
function gt(year,month,day) {
        return new Date(year,month-1,day).getTime();
    }
</script>
     <label for="eingabe">
   Ihr Name:
   <input id="feld" name="eingabe" />
 </label>
 <button id="knopf" type="button" onclick="NameEinfg()">
    Klick mich!
 </button>
 <div id="bereich"></div>

 <script>
    function NameEinfg(){
       if (document.getElementById('feld').value==''){
          document.getElementById('bereich').innerHTML ="Hallo Unbekannter";}
       else {
          document.getElementById('bereich').innerHTML =document.getElementById('feld').style.display = 'block';}
       }
   </script>
```

`

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Use `display: none` for the style of your chart then add `document.getElementById('barchart').style.display = 'block';` in your onclick function, and that should probably do the trick.

As for the name, since you know how to retrieve the input value of the field, I'm sure you can figure it out by yourself!

Comment: When I do that, no matter what I type in the box, I just shows me `'block'`

Comment: That's weird. I don't see how css style could become html content like that. Can we have a screengrab of the result/an extract of your code ?

Comment: `<script> function NameEinfg(){document.getElementById('feld').style.display = 'block'}</script>` is what you need to write, not set the inner html to "block"....

Comment: Now, nothing happens, when I type `barchart`

Comment: I suppose you actually clicked on the button too ? Did you use inline css or a <style> tag ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't really know much about Javascript. I just copied what you wrote into my code instead of the other NameEinfg function that I had

Comment: And yes, I klicked the button ;)

Comment: Just saw it was inline css. I think I know the problem : it should not be 'feld' but 'barchart' in the `getElementById` selector in the function.

Comment: But I want to be able to have several "hidden" charts. If I fix this there, I won't be able to access more than one, right? Also, I tried this and it didn't show me anything again

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. You want to display them all with the same button ? `document.getElementsByClassName('chart')` is what you want -- after attributing the 'chart' class, of course.

Comment: I want to type something in the Box, say "Example", and then show the chart with the id "Example"